# How to use same java method for different parameters types?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My problem:

I have 2 defined records

- CreateObjectRequest
- UpdateObjectRequest

that must be verified by an utility method.

As those 2 objects have the same fields, the same verify method can be applied on both types.
Right now I'm just overloading by using 2 methods, but it's verbosy.

```java
public record CreateObjectRequest (
    CustomObjectA a,
    CustomObjectB b,
    CustomObjectC c
) {}
public record UpdateObjectRequest (
    CustomObjectA a,
    CustomObjectB b
) {}

public void validateRequest(CreateObjectRequest createObjectRequest) {
    //long body
    //...
}
public void validateRequest(UpdateObjectRequest updateObjectRequest) {
    //same long body... 
    //...
}
```

How can I reduce the verbosity of this code ?

Answer (score 1):

If those 2 classes share a lot of the same fields and are related to one another, then creating an Abstract parent class would be a solution:

```
public abstract class ObjectRequest {
    CustomObject a;
    CustomObject b;

}
```

then have your other classes extend that class via inheritance:

```
public class CreateObjectRequest extends ObjectRequest {
    // any fields / method that are specific to this class
}

public class UpdateObjectRequest extends ObjectRequest {
    // any fields / method that are specific to this class
}
```

And you can then define your validation method to take the abstract Superclass as an argument:

```
public void validateRequest(ObjectRequest objectRequest) {
    //long body
    //...
}
```

Comment: I eddited my question, actually, I'm dealing with records. And they cannot implements abstract methods

Answer (score 0):

Make one interface and make this objects implements it.
Then you can put this interface as argument in your methods.

Comment: An abstract class might be better suited, because fields in interfaces is not really possible.

Comment: @ThomasBehr I agree. Abstract class is better here.

Comment: I edited my question, actually i'm dealing with records, not classes, so I guess this answer is the only solution I have